# How do I query for two columns to be equal using Sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

```
db.WorkbookQuestion.count({
  where: {
    QuestionId: dbQuestion.id,
    AnswerSelectedId: db.sequelize.col('CorrectAnswerId')
  }
});
```

The query generates this SQL: `SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "WorkbookQuestions" AS "WorkbookQuestion" WHERE "WorkbookQuestion"."QuestionId" = 1103 AND "CorrectAnswerId";`

How do I get it to be more like `AnswerSelectedId = CorrectAnswerId`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it via `sequelize.where()`:

```
db.WorkbookQuestion.count({
  where: sequelize.where(
    db.sequelize.col('CorrectAnswerId'),
    db.sequelize.col('AnswerSelectedId')
  )
});
```

Comment: What if I want to have multiple clauses?

Comment: @Shamoon have you tried to put the conditions into an array? Something like: `where: [sequelize.where(..), sequelize.where(..)]`. Not tested - will actually experiment if this is not going to work. Thanks.

Comment: Using `where: [sequelize.where(..), sequelize.where(..)]` causes a `sql.replace is not a function` error.

Answer (score 10):

I was stuck on this for a while today until I found this answer. I also found another way of doing the same query so will leave another answer here.

```
db.WorkbookQuestion.count({
  where: {
    CorrectAnswerId: {
        $col: 'AnswerSelectedId'
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Another way of writing code by using Operators(Op) from sequelize.

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize');

db.WorkbookQuestion.count({
  where: {
    QuestionId: dbQuestion.id,
    CorrectAnswerId: {
        [Op.eq]: sequelize.col('AnswerSelectedId')
    }
  }
});
```